# Optimizing MySQL queries / database structure

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have in my MySQL database these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `img` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url_key` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type_code` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `likes_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url_key` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`code`),
  KEY `type` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

And I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM `articles` a INNER JOIN articles_types at ON at.`code`=a.type ORDER BY p.likes_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which returns 1 row, in **1sec**.

The table articles consists of aproximately over 70k rows, articles_types only about 70 rows.

Is there any chance to optimize the structure (maybe engine?) of that tables, or optimize the query itself to make it faster?

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables? If so let us know which columns are covered.

Comment: 2Dustin: As you may see above, the tables consists of many indexes, now I've added a new index to articles.like_count, because the results are sorted by this column. But it didn't helped.

Comment: 2Damien: Thanks for considiring about that :-) Trust me, if I'd get really answer, which would solve my problems, I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should examine the output of [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) on your query

It's likely the order by that gets you, so create an index on articles.likes_count

Comment: You're absolutely right. The problem here is the ORDERing - but even after adding the index to articles.likes_count, it takes 1-2sec.Without sorting results (without ORDER BY) its very fast - e.g. 0.0004sec.

Comment: It helped to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. Perhaps it may happend, that will appears an article with unknown category, so I'll have to check that in application.